# Wrong answer due to precision issues?

Tags: c++, debugging, precision, traveling-salesman

I am implementing Greedy Approach to TSP:

1. Start from first node.
2. Go to nearest node not visited yet. (If multiple, go to the one with the lowest index.)
3. Don't forget to include distance from node 1 to last node visited.

However, my code gives the wrong answer. I implemented the same code in Python and the python code gives right answer.

In my problem, the nodes are coordinates on 2-D plane and the distance is the Euclidean Distance.

I even changed everything to `long double` because it's more precise.

In fact, if I reverse the order of the `for` loop to reverse the direction and add an additional `if` statement to handle ties (we want minimum index nearest node), it gives a very different answer.

Is this because of precision issues?

(Note: I have to print `floor(ans)`)

INPUT: [Link](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_ae5a820392a02042f87e3b437876cf19_nn.txt?Expires=1664236800&Signature=aZEObPhY5kiDJYAZHm1%7EVn6sqZ-kERlijXRZCWhtDUb8%7Ex6t-7Z24aymavRBnH%7ECNeT9f1IdZh%7ESZGRDR7vrYoeoVYldId3xZ9EmO6yp1JHF9Shwal0MYJLhC0ew9vAA9zZJ6EK-gpLkvU1aIl9kdA30feFA-LcY-yqI4qia6OU_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

EXPECTED OUTPUT: 1203406

ACTUAL OUTPUT: 1200403

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<pair<long double, long double>> points(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        assert(x == i + 1);

        cin >> points[i].first >> points[i].second;
    }

    // Returns the squared Euclidean Distance
    function<long double(int, int)> dis = [&](int x, int y) {
        long double ans = (points[x].first - points[y].first) * (points[x].first - points[y].first);
        ans += (points[x].second - points[y].second) * (points[x].second - points[y].second);
        return ans;
    };

    long double ans = 0;
    int last = 0;
    int cnt = n - 1;
    vector<int> taken(n, 0);
    taken[0] = 1;

    while (cnt > 0) {
        pair<long double, int> mn = {1e18, 1e9};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (!taken[i]) {
                mn = min(mn, {dis(i, last), i});
            }
        }

        int nex = mn.second;
        taken[nex] = 1;
        cnt--;
        ans += sqrt(mn.first);
        last = nex;
    }

    ans += sqrt(dis(0, last));
    cout << ans << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: Python Code:

```
import math

file = open("input.txt", "r")

n = int(file.readline())

a = []
for i in range(n):
    data = file.readline().split(" ")
    a.append([float(data[1]), float(data[2])])

for c in a:
    print(c)


def dis(x, y):
    cur_ans = (a[x][0] - a[y][0]) * (a[x][0] - a[y][0])
    cur_ans += (a[x][1] - a[y][1]) * (a[x][1] - a[y][1])
    cur_ans = math.sqrt(cur_ans)
    return cur_ans


ans = 0.0
last = 0
cnt = n - 1
take = []
for i in range(n):
    take.append(0)
take[0] = 1

while cnt > 0:
    idx = -1
    cur_dis = 1e18
    for i in range(n):
        if take[i] == 0:
            if dis(i, last) < cur_dis:
                cur_dis = dis(i, last)
                idx = i

    assert(idx != -1)
    take[idx] = 1
    cnt -= 1
    ans += cur_dis
    last = idx

ans += dis(0, last)

print(ans)

file.close()

# 1203406
```

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit `int`, it can store values from about minus two billion to just over plus two billion. `1e18` is much larger than that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry that's a typo. In the original code I had `{1e9, 1e9}` but later changed the code to `{1e18, 1e9}` while writing the question. In the question itself, I accidentally set both `1e18`.

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the actual and expected output

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles The code is complete. If you're talking about includes and input reading, I added those

Comment: It is hard to say. In theory, you do have some calculations that could lead to cancellatio errors, such as calculating the difference of similar numbers and performing many additions on these differences. To really check if your code behaves differently to your python version, it would helpt to see your python code here. For debugging, I would create a MUCH smaller example, which you could theoretically check with pen and paper. This example could serve as a unit test for your code.

Comment: @joergbrech I have added my Python code.

Comment: @joergbrech I tried some small cases by hand in c++ code but they work fine.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `points[x]` is `long double`, so I don't think there is overflow there. Also, `ans` can have decimal values, that's why it's `long double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the difference is due to round-off error, with the C++ code producing the more accurate result because of your use of `long double`. If you change your C++ code, such that it uses the same precision as Python *(IEEE-754, meaning `double` precision)* you get the exact same round-off errors in both codes. Here is a demonstrator in Godbolt Compiler explorer, with your example boiled down to 4000 points: https://godbolt.org/z/rddrdT54n

If I run the same code on the whole input file I get 1203406.5012708856 in C++ and in Python *(Had to try this offline, because Godbolt understandibly killed the process)*.

Note, that in theory your Python-Code and C++ code are not completely analogous, because `std::min` will compare tuples and pairs **lexicographically**. So if you ever have two distances exactly equal, the `std::min` call will choose the smaller of the two indices. Practically, this does not make a difference, though.

Now I don't think you really can get rid off the rounding errors. There are a few tricks to minimize them.

- using higher precision (`long double`) is one option. But this also makes your code slower, it's a tradeoff
- Rescale your points, so that they are relative to the centroid of all points, and the unit reflects your problem (e.g. don't think in mm, miles, km or whatever, but rather in "variance of your data set"). You can't get rid of numerical cancellation in your calculation of the Euclidean distance, but if the relative distances are small compared to the absolute values of the coordinates, the cancellation is typically more severe. Here is a small demonstration:

  ```cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>

  int main() {
      std::cout 
          << std::setprecision(17)
          << (1000.0001 - 1000)/0.0001
          << std::endl
          << (1.0001 - 1)/0.0001
          << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  ```
  0.99999999974897946
  0.99999999999988987
  ```
- Finally, there are some tricks and algorithms to better control the error accumulation in large sums *(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)*

One final comment, a bit unrelated to your question: Use `auto` with lambdas, i.e.

```cpp
auto dis = [&](int x, int y) {
    // ...
};
```

C++ has many different kinds of callable objects *(functions, function pointers, functors, lambdas, ...)* and `std::function` is a useful wrapper to have one type representing all kinds of callables with the same signature. This comes at some computational overhead (runtime polymorphism, type erasure) and the compiler will have a hard time optimizing your code. So if you don't need the type erasing functionality of `std::function`, just store your lambda in a variable declared with `auto`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I have a question though: "with the C++ code producing the more accurate result because of your use of `long double`" Does this mean that the C++ answer is actually right and Python answer is wrong? I am given that `1203406` is the answer the heuristic should produce though.

Comment: "Right and wrong" are maybe not the correct terms, because as long as you use floating points, you always have round-off errors. How do you know `1203406 ` is the exact answer? Is this just a numerical reference solution obtained using floating point calculations with `double` precision? Or has this been verified analytically somehow? I would be surprised...

Comment: I am given that `1203406` is the `floor(ans)` the heuristic should produce.

Comment: Ok, but how did the person that gave you this solution obtain this solution? If it is a numerical reference solution, it has round-off errors.

Comment: Yeah, that may be possible. Thanks again for the answer!